# Spotfire DateDiff Using Custom Expression

Tags: expression, datediff, spotfire

I am attempting to calculate the number of years between MIN date and MAX date on a filtered date column then divide the result by a COUNT of Column Y OVER Column X.

Spotfire documentation says that Custom Expressions are the key to manipulating filtered data, but I’m not sure how to pass temporary variables to a Spotfire function like DateDiff.

```
Example:
DateDiff(Min([Date]),Max([Date])) / [Column.Y] OVER [Column.X]

 +------+----------+------------+
 | Name |   Date   | Made Sale? |
 +------+----------+------------+
 | joe  | 1/1/2010 | 10         |
 | joe  | 2/1/2011 | 11         |
 | joe  | 3/1/2012 |            |
 | joe  | 4/1/2013 | 40         |
 | joe  | 5/1/2014 |            |
 | pam  | 1/1/2010 | 100        |
 | pam  | 2/1/2011 | 19         |
 | pam  | 3/1/2012 | 23         |
 | pam  | 4/1/2013 | 30         |
 | pam  | 5/1/2014 |            |
 | mark | 1/1/2010 |            |
 | mark | 2/1/2011 | 1          |
 | mark | 3/1/2012 |            |
 | mark | 4/1/2013 |            |
 | mark | 5/1/2014 | 49         |
 +------+----------+------------+
EG. Filter from 2011-2014, what were Joe, Pam, and Mark's frequency of sales per year?
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data. Like 6 to 10 rows showing what you need to attain ?

Comment: Updated, does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap this in a logical statement like IF() or CASE.

```
If(DatePart('year',[Date]) >= Year('2011') and DatePart('year',[Date]) <= Year('2014'),DateDiff(Min([Date]),Max([Date])) / [Column.Y] OVER [Column.X])
```

You can use a property control and pass in any inputted or calculated years in place of the '2011' and '2014'. It would look something like

```
Year('${yourPropertyControlName}')
```